# Elasticsearch Python update list field to have just the first value in the list

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an index with documents in the format below:

```
{
"_index": "index",
"_type": "entities",
"_id": "577391",
"_score": 10.449369,
"_source": {
"links": [
    "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/White_American>",
    "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alabama>",
    "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alaska>"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to keep only the first link in the list of links.

Note: I want to keep the list, I just want to keep one value in this list.

How do I update the index to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new List and Copy the old one over with a for-loop. When you come to the "links" section instead of copying it completely you just copy the first index of the array. Keep in mind that you'll have to change the Datatype (List is a String Array atm, but the value will be a single String if you only copy one).

Comment: I'm new to elasticseach and I have a really big index about 700k documents Please elaborate on how I could do this for the entire index?